# dplyr how to summarize and split result from a function that returns a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi suppose I need to summarize by gene from this data.frame here.

```
g1 = data.frame ( 
      gene = c( "a","a","a","a","b"),
      value = c(1,200,3,5,0)
    )
  gene value
1    a     1
2    a   200
3    a     3
4    a     5
5    b     0
```

What I want to do is aggregate by gene, but using a function that returns two variables.  For this example lets say this function returns a mean and median.

```
mn <- function ( x ){
    return  ( c( median(x), mean(x) ))
}
```

Because the function returns a vector I need to call it twice.  Is there a way to split the result up so that I don't have to calculate it twice?

```
g1 %>%
    group_by(gene) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(
        median = mn ( value )[1],  # because mn returns a vector I need to call it twice
        mean = mn ( value )[2]
    ) %>%
    data.frame()
```

Comment: Why not just have separate functions for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with dplyr, though it's not necessarily as intuitive as other solutions. The `do()` function will work however. NOTE - I modified your `mn()` function to assign names to the vector that is returned.

Here's the [reference page](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/do.html) for `do()`. The tricky part is how you pass in the object with the `.$` notation.

```r
library(dplyr)
g1 = data.frame ( 
  gene = c( "a","a","a","a","b"),
  value = c(1,200,3,5,0)
)

mn <- function (x){
  return(c(median = median(x), mean = mean(x)))
}


g1 %>% group_by(gene) %>% 
  do(data.frame(t(mn(.$value)))) %>%
  data.frame()
#>   gene median  mean
#> 1    a      4 52.25
#> 2    b      0  0.00
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Without diverting into a deep dive between `data.table` and `dplyr`, here's a timing comparison between the two solutions on a moderately sized chunk of data:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
#function
mn <- function (x){
  return(list(median = median(x), mean = mean(x)))
}

#bigger data
g1 = data.frame( 
  gene = gl(1e5, 1e2),
  value = rnorm(1e8)
)

f_dt <- function() setDT(g1)[, mn(value), by = gene]
f_dp <- function() g1 %>% group_by(gene) %>% do(data.frame(t(mn(.$value)))) %>% data.frame()

system.time(f_dt())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   11.00    1.53   15.35
system.time(f_dp())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   38.09    0.37   39.94
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: This is an interesting solution.  I'm wondering if this will effect the speed on a much bigger data.frame.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ahdee - my hunch is `data.table()` will prove magnitudes faster as the data expands.

Comment: @Ahdee - check out timing comparison. In this example, `data.table()` is ~2.5x faster.

Comment: Another option would be to `summarise` as a `list` and then `unnest` assuming that the initial function outputs a `tibble` or `data.frame` `mn <- function(x) tibble(median = median(x), mean = mean(x));
 g1 %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise(out = list(mn(value))) %>% unnest`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `dplyr` but you can do it with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

g1 = data.table ( 
  gene = c( "a","a","a","a","b"),
  value = c(1,200,3,5,0))


mn <- function(x){
  return(list(med = median(x), mean = mean(x)))
}


g1[, mn(value), by = gene]
```